# Cannot install Microsoft Web Farm Framework v2.2

Tags: iis-7, webdeploy, web-platform-installer, web-farm-framework

Trying to install Microsoft Web Farm Framework v2.2 on a Windows 2008 server.

I've already downloaded and installed Web PI v3 after realising v4 is too new to be able to download the Web Farm Framework.

When I run the installer for the Web Farm Framework v2.2 I get the following error:

```
Web Deployment Tool is a pre-requisite for installing Web Farm Framework. Please install the Web Deployment tool.
```

The strange thing here is that Web Deploy is already installed (v3.0).  So I then try and download v3.5 assuming there is a problem with the current version at v3. 
However when I try to install this I get the following error:

```
Failed to instal Web Platform Installer. Lick OK to use the browser to download installer.
```

Can anyone help to get this working?
Not sure why it wants me to open another browser window since I just came from a browser to install the extension?  So it seems I cannot install something because there is a dependency on something else, yet I can't install that dependency either.

Why is this so difficult and why hasn't Microsoft made this easier to install?

Answer (score 1):

I got this working in the end. Basically you need to just install everything in sequence starting with the Web PI v3 then Web Deploy v2 followed by the Web Farm Framework. It seems there is a dependency on specific versions on each of the required tools. Not sure why it insists on opening a browser window again though.

Comment: I'm having the same problem on windows server 2008 R2. Installed web deploy, web platform 3.0, then tried to install farm framework 2.2 but it fails saying that I need WebDeploy. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered this issue and tried the registry modification which helped me out.

Try changing the registry setting  install the module and change the registry back to the original value.

`Open Regedit > HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp
Edit "MajorVersion" and set the "HexaDecimal" value to 9
Install the WebFarm 2.2 module.
Change the "MajorVersion" back to "HexaDecimal" value of a
Hit F5 while in Regedit
Close Regedit`